# Unity OnStateExit StateMachineBehaviour is never getting called

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script attached to my Animation state as shown below:
[image: animatio]

The script is as follows:

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class TrackHelpDuration : StateMachineBehaviour 
{
     // OnStateEnter is called when a transition starts and the state machine starts to evaluate this state
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) 
    {
        Debug.Log("entering state");
        if (GameSession.timeSpentOnRemedialHint > 0)
            GameSession.updateTime(11);
    }

    // OnStateExit is called when a transition ends and the state machine finishes evaluating this state
    override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) 
    {
        Debug.Log("exiting state");
        if (GameSession.timeSpentOnRemedialHint > 0)
            GameSession.updateTime(11);
    }
}
```

While `OnStateEnter` is working as expected, `OnStateExit` is never getting called. How do I make it work?

---

I found an issue which says the same thing, but that was 3 years ago.
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/mecanim-onstateexit-method-never-gets-called-when-next-state-becomes-active

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: I ended up not using `OnStateExit`

Answer (score 3):

this is a late answer but probably will help others that have the same issue.

```
override public void OnStateExit
```

The callback will automatically be called when "STATE CHANGES" which means when "Exit On Current State", probably you assume it called when animation finished.

**TL;DR.**

**you have to move the animation state to another state in terms of call that function.
hope it helps**